# Verilog d flipflop circuit testing

Tags: testing, verilog, circuit, flip-flop

I'm trying to construct a structural implementation of a circuit that consists of a d flipflop, it has inputs x and y, x and y are exclusive or'd and that result is exclusive or'd with the current state, and used as the input to the d flip flop. and it'll use the result state from the flipflop in the next run, etc. But I'm not too sure how to construct it.

The circuit looks like so:
[image]

```
module dff(D,clk,q);
input D,clk;
output q;
reg q;
always @ (posedge clk)
 begin
  q<=D;
 end
endmodule
```

I'm pretty sure the d flip flop code is correct but when I try to test this my d and state values are just x for some reason. When I put in different x and y values in my testbench nothing happens, "state" and "d" just always says it has value "1'hx" in the simulation. Why is this happening and how do I actually assign an value to them?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the clock signal? Please add you testbench code to your question so we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All signals in verilog simulation are initialized to 'x'. So are the values of `A` and `D`. Your second `xor` is applied to `xoy ^ A`. Since `A`  is `x`, the result of this xor is always `x`. you need to break this loop, as oldfart suggested.

The usual way for doing it is to introduce a `reset` in the flop, synchronous or asynchronous. Here is an example of a synchronous reset flop:

```
always @(posedge clk)
    if (reset)
        q <= 0;
    else 
        q <= D;
```

So, now, if you set your reset to '1' for at least one posedge of clk and then set it to '0', you will break the loop by pushing a non-'x' value in the data path.

Answer (score 0):

You do not clear your D-FF. The output is X at the start and as you use that in a feedback loop it stays X.

This: `wire state=1'b0;` does not clear you FF. You have to clear 'q'.